# Picking up keystrokes Ctrl-Alt-Q

Tags: c#, winforms

What's the 'correct/best' way to pick up a keystroke combination?  The keys in question are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, I want the user to press them all at the same time, at which point I am going to open a window.  I'm currently doing it by have an array and then catching each keystroke individually, but my results are inconsistent, especially on a particular make of Dell laptop/windows 7 combination, but that's another story.

So after spending five minutes with google, this is just a rough version after looking at the msdn, but as I stated earlier is this version (untested) the correct/best way of doing it?

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)    
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

    if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
    {
        switch(keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.Q:
            this.Parent.Text="<CTRL> + Alt + Q Captured";
            break;
        }               
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg,keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignore msg.Msg, only look at keyData.  And return true without calling base if you use the keystroke.  Which simplifies it to:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)    
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.Q)) {
        this.Parent.Text="<CTRL> + Alt + Q Captured";
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg,keyData);
}
```

This should probably be an override of the *form's* method so you don't depend on the control having the focus.  You'd use this.Text instead.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's on the form, not a control.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how I would do it if I wish to listen for key events **globally**.

But if you are interested in keyboard inputs ONLY when your program is the focused window (in the front on Windows), you might want to use the KeyDown event:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
 // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for System.Windows.Forms.Keys, you cannot use a bitwise OR to check for key combinations. The documentation states: "For finer control, use the Win32 API functions GetKeyState, GetAsyncKeyState, or GetKeyboardState defined in user32.dll...". But it appears that Shift, Alt and Control can be used as bitwise flags.

Comment: No, you are quoting the values of Keys.ControlKey and Keys.Menu.  Keys.Control and Keys.Alt have very different values (0x20000, 0x40000).  They are bit flags.  Your answer is sending the user into a pinvoke rabbit hole for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks Hans you saved me some time there :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who wants open a windows or make visible/invisible with the combination of three keys (with two modifiers) by the light of @Hans Passant i found finally an answer to my problem. I was beware of | operand, putting instead && operand which was not working. It can be assigned to WFA properties to Keydown

```
private void ShowHidden_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.M) )
        {
            OldBisProdId.Visible = true;
            OldGanProdId.Visible = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.C))
        {
            OldBisProdId.Visible = false;
            OldGanProdId.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```