# How can I simulate Ctrl+Alt+H using keybd_event in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, keypress

How can I simulate Ctrl+Alt+H using keybd_event() ? The following code , doesn't work :

```
    keybd_event((byte)Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control), (byte)MapVirtualKey(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control), 0), 0, 0);
        keybd_event((byte)Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Alt), (byte)MapVirtualKey(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Alt), 0), 0, 0);
        keybd_event((byte)Keys.H, (byte)MapVirtualKey(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.H), 0), 0, 0);
        keybd_event((byte)Keys.H, (byte)MapVirtualKey(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.H), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        keybd_event((byte)Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Alt), (byte)MapVirtualKey(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Alt), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        keybd_event((byte)Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control), (byte)MapVirtualKey(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: did you google and didnt find any answer?!

Comment: "doesn't work" can mean a lot of things e.g. (nothing happened, exception, the wrong thing happened, random things happen, etc) Can you please be specific

Comment: On winform.....actually nothing happens........I was able to raise Ctrl+H , but nothing happens when I tried Ctrl+Alt+H!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SendKeys to do this:

```
SendKeys.Send("^%H");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

**EDIT**
(See comments below...)

You want to launch a windows shortcut on your desktop that you have setup with a specific set of hot keys.  In this case CTRL+ALT+H.  You want to write an app that will execute that shortcut key combination.

In order for this to work your desktop will have to have "focus".  This means that no other windows should be up.  So, start your application, minimize all other windows, and then press the button on your application.  Here is the code you should have behind your button:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        SendKeys.SendWait("^%h");
    }
```

This will minimize the current window thus giving focus to your desktop.  It will then send the CTRL and ALT and H keys to the desktop which will launch your shortcut.

Comment: I tried that , and nothing happens.... I think something is wrong...Here is my code :

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sa1FCxiR

Comment: The code you posted will send the keys to THAT form (the one where you pressed the button) is that intended?  If you want to send the keys to another window, then the window/form that you want to receive the keys will have to be active and front-most.

Comment: My mistake , I expected it to raise global key press event.Well, then how can I raise global Ctrl+Alt+H key press event?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "global".  Key presses need to be consumed by something.  If you are in Word, then word is consuming them.  If you are in a game, then that game is consuming them.  If there are no windows up then your desktop is consuming them.  If you want your key strokes to be consumed by a specific window, that window has to be font and center just like if YOU were putting in the key strokes from your keyboard.  You can use calls to find the window and bring it forward before sending the key strokes if you want as well.

Comment: I need to send the keys to the desktop ?

Comment: **I** don't know where you need to send the keys.  What application are you trying to send the Ctrl+Alt+H to???

Comment: I'm using Windows XP. I placed a shortcut(*.lnk) on my desktop(home) with the keys Ctrl+Alt+H.... that points to on of my apps... and gets activated when I press..... Ctrl+Alt+H .... I tried to activate my app via the shortcut(*.lnk) from another program......I know it can be done in other ways or directly calling my app or the shortcut(*lnk)....., but I just wanted to see , if I can activate my program via the shortcut(*lnk) raising Ctrl+Alt+H press from another program.

Comment: I updated my answer above with a solution that should work for you.  See the EDIT section.

Comment: Still couldn't get it worked! I placed the code behind my button.. Don't know what's happening ???

Comment: My modified code : [link](http://pastebin.com/W7dPCdSk)

Comment: This worked just fine for me.  Most likely you still have a window open that is catching the keys.  Try running your app, minimizing all windows using WINDOWSKEY + M, then clicking your DESKTOP, then clicking your app, then clicking your button.

Comment: Still! ..don't know what's happening...        .I tried Win+M ........ , nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

You should override `ProcessCmdKey` method.

See this link :

[Picking up keystrokes Ctrl-Alt-Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029548/picking-up-keystrokes-ctrl-alt-q)

Comment: that seems limited to winforms though